# How to make a string from a BegDecimal number which contained only the integral part

Tags: java, string, bigdecimal

My question is about of `toString()` and `toPlainString()` methods of the `BigDecimal` dataTypewhich produces the output like

```
750.0000
150.0000
... etc
```

My question is how to specify the number of zeros followed after the dot? Is there a way to do it instead of `String.replace(".0000", ".00")` method?

Comment: Have you tried using `DecimalFormat`?

Comment: @JonSkeet No, I haven't. Couldn't you provide an example?

Comment: @St.Antario There is a documentation which is pretty well descriptive, I suggest you to have a look :-)

Comment: @ZouZou Yeah, indeed. I just didn't know about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from decimal format you can also use `setScale(2)` like this

```
new BigDecimal("1.0000").setScale(2)
```

Also [setScale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale(int)) allows you can specify the [Rounding Mode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html)

Comment: No, because I think it doesn't affect to either toString or toPlainString methods which essentially produce the String.

Comment: @St.Antario try System.out.println(new BigDecimal("1.0000").setScale(2)); and you will see

Comment: Ah, exactly. I tried to look at the implementation of toPlainString and understood why it worked so. Thank you.

Comment: @St.Antario i added the link to documentation as well. Glad it helps

Answer (score 2):

Use [`DecimalFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormat.html) in combination with `DecimalFormatSymbols`:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols dfs = new DecimalFormatSymbols(); 
dfs.setDecimalSeparator('.');
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat("##.##");
df.setDecimalFormatSymbols(dfs);

df.format(myNumber)
```

Without using `DecimalFormatSymbols` you would end up with a comma as a decimal seperator instead.

Answer (score 2):

Please use the below code.

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();

nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2); 

String s = nf.format(1111.2222);

System.out.println(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use [setScale](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#setScale%28int%29) method and optinally you could choose rounding methodology of your own. Somethign like:

```
 BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal("750.0000");
 b.setScale(2);
```